# Start a new terminal instance if window splitting was initiated from a terminal buffer

Tags: neovim, terminal, terminal-buffer

When I'm in the terminal and I press `<C-w>s` the screen is split vertically and the terminal buffer is shown twice. Then I have to do `:terminal` if I want a separate terminal instance.

Typing something in one window is in real time shown in the other. This is a *feature* if I was editing a file but is an *inconvenience* when working with terminal buffers.

> How do I conditionally run `<C-w>S:terminal` depending on whether the current window is a terminal buffer?

Comment: You could probably setup terminal mappings with tnoremap

Answer (score 1):

This is a documented 'feature' of `:tnoremap` as `tnoremap` effectively only work for insert mode style actions and thus any variant using `tmap` will not work.

Adding the below to `init.vim` will remap the action of Ctrl-w + s in normal mode only for the terminal buffer

`autocmd BufWinEnter,WinEnter term://* nnoremap <buffer> <C-w>s <C-\><C-n><C-w><C-v> :terminal <CR>`

as mentioned in the comments, it is better to use `augroup NAME` before this command (and `augroup END`) so that you don't add this command multiple times when your rc file is being sourced. It's also suggested practice that you place all the relevant terminal-specific commands in this augroup.

Comment: You should mention `:h augroup` and why OP should wrap autocommands in augroups.

Answer (score 1):

The following function will `:h :split` the current buffer and create a new terminal buffer if the current buffer is a terminal buffer. Otherwise it will just `:h :split`. Bind this function to both `:h :nnoremap` and `:h :tnoremap` variants of mappings to get the required results.

```
function! TermSplit() abort
    if exists('b:term_title')
        split
        terminal
    else
        split
    endif
endfunction

tnoremap <C-w>s <C-\><C-N>:call TermSplit()<CR>
nnoremap <C-w>s :call TermSplit()<CR>
```

**PS** You can create similar function and bind it to `<C-w>v` for `:h :vsplit`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to `~/.config/init.vim` solved it:

```
" Split into a new terminal instance                       
tnoremap <C-w>s <C-\><C-n><C-w><C-s> :terminal <CR>
tnoremap <C-w>v <C-\><C-n><C-w><C-v> :terminal <CR>
set splitbelow                                     
set splitright
```

It maps the split commands (`<C-w>s` and `<C-w>v`) to the following action:

1. `<C-\><C-n>` - exit insert mode in terminal
2. `<C-w><C-v>` - run the actual split command
3. `:terminal` - unter the terminal command
4. `<CR>` - press enter

The additional two commands make the newly opened terminal doesn't appear on the location of the previous one.

Comment: This works if the terminal is in insert mode, but is still splits into the same terminal if it's executed from normal mode.

Comment: Create a function that checks if the current buffer is terminal, and act accordingly. Then map the keys to that function. I added an answer with such a function.